# Substring returning opposite results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Javascript .substring() to retrieve only the price part of a string.

I know this can be done using Regex but I want to solve it using .substring().

I defined the starting and ending values for .substring() and instead of getting the value in the middle: **5.75** ... I am getting only the parts of the string that I do not need **US::Air:** & **USD** from the string **"US::Air:5.75 USD"**.

Could someone give some quick advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
var cat = "US::Air:5.75 USD"
var firstPart = cat.lastIndexOf(":") + 1;
console.log(firstPart);
var secondPart = cat.split(" ")[1];
console.log(secondPart);
var betweenFirstNSecond = cat.substring(firstPart, secondPart);
console.log(betweenFirstNSecond);
```

Expected outcome: 5.75
Actual outcome from console logs: 
        11 
        USD 
        US::Air:

Comment: secondpart is an string not an `number` you need to pass a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to split. You should just get position where you want to get new string and position where you want to stop subtract:

```
let str = "US::Air:5.75 USD";
let subStr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1, str.lastIndexOf(' '));
console.log(subStr);
```

OR:

```
let str = "US::Air:5.75 USD";
let startToSubtract = str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1;
let endToSubtract = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
let subStr = str.substring(startToSubtract, endToSubtract);
console.log(subStr);
```

Comment: This will work for me... targeting the last index of " " as the end value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Any argument value that is `NaN` is treated as if it were 0.

Since the value of second part is string, when you try to change it number it will result in `NaN`

```js
console.log(+"USD")
```

---

> If indexStart is greater than indexEnd, then the effect of substring()
>   is as if the two arguments were swapped;

so your code is actually doing `str.substring(0, lastIndexOf(":") + 1)` and you end up getting values upto last `:`, instead you can take lastIndexOf of space character or whatever separator you have

```js
var cat = "US::Air:5.75 USD";
var firstPart = cat.lastIndexOf(":") + 1;
var secondPart = cat.indexOf(" ");
var firstMinusSecond = cat.substring(firstPart, secondPart);
console.log(firstMinusSecond);
```

Comment: As the currency might change, I wanted to avoid using ".indexOf" to target only "USD"

Comment: @Dan you can take last index of space character instead, i just used it to show how to do it, the main problem was using `secondPart` as index

Answer (score 0):

1. The substring() method treats any argument as 0 if its value is NaN.
2. The substring() method swaps its two arguments if start index is
   greater than end index.

In your code, the start index is 8  and end index in "USD" which is NaN.
Hence  substring method treats end index as 0.
Now since start index 8 is greater than end index 0 , the two arguments are swapped.
This finally results into method substring(0,8) which yields USD US::Air:

Kindly refer to MDN documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring